# jQuery addClass() method

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to highlight a table row with a specific item ID (in first column) by updating its CSS class, but it is not working:

```
.inactive {
  background-color: "red";
}
```

My code calls the following JavaScript function whenever a specific event happens:

```
function highlight_item(item_id){
  var tableRow = $("#itemsTable tr td:first-child").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == item_id
  }).parent();
  tableRow.addClass("inactive")
}
```

Strangely, it works if I replace the `addClass()` call with

```
tableRow.css("backgroundColor", "red")
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the quotes from "red". Use `.inactive { background-color: red; }`

Comment: Thanks, that was it! Constant switching between syntaxes of CSS, Javascript and a server-side language script always makes me make these silly mistakes.